# Ayuda con Select -> Option -> value=" "

Tags: html, base-de-datos

Me muestra lo que tengo en la base de datos pero solo el id, Al parecer me hace falta en la consulta

```html
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bienes Asegurados</label>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-8">
                                        <select name="TipoOperacion" id="tipoOperacion" required title="Seleccionar tipo de contenedor" class="form-control m-b" required>
                                        <option value="0">Selecciona el tipo de contenedor</option><?php $result=query("SELECT * FROM coberturas;");while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></option>
                                         <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

Esta es la consulta

```html
$result=query("SELECT  clientes.RazonSocial, clientes.RFC, clientes.Calle, clientes.Colonia, 
    clientes.Municipio, clientes.Estado, clientes.CP,
    merca.idViaje, merca.idCliente, merca.Cliente, merca.rfc, merca.moneda, 
    merca.mercancia, merca.importe, merca.TipoOperacion, merca.FechaAlta, 
    merca.detalles, merca.TipoTransporte, merca.FechaSalida, merca.FechaLlegada, 
    merca.folio, merca.porigen, merca.eorigen, merca.corigen, merca.pdestino, 
    merca.edestino, merca.cdestino, merca.Coberturas1, merca.Coberturas2, merca.Coberturas3, merca.Coberturas4, merca.poliza, merca.cuota, merca.prima, merca.gastosexp, 
    merca.iva, merca.total, coberturas.id, coberturas.nombre
FROM clientes join merca ON clientes.idCliente = merca.idCliente join coberturas ON coberturas.id = merca.TipoOperacion WHERE idViaje=".$idViaje);
```

Comment: Hola Isaias Alejandro, no termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema que estás encontrando. ¿A qué te refieres? ¿De dónde obtienes los valores ahora y dónde los guardas?

Comment: No tengo ningún problema, lo que pasa es que he visto que en vez de como yo tengo el value ponen 0, 1, 3 y así sucesivamente, no los guardo en ningun lugar he ahi mi pregunta si necesito crear una tabla con esos values para yo nomas poner value ="1" y me ponga en una tabla nueva el valor ya asignado al 1

Comment: Saludos en que lenguaje vas a realizar eso en php ? para llenar el select desde und BD

Comment: Pues creo yo que si seria en PHP, por el momento solo lo tengo en html asignados los values

Answer (score 0):

Saludos primero que nada deberías definir tu tabla, asumiendo Mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tipoOperacion (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    estado INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

La tabla se llamara **tipoOperacion**  la misma pose ID que es autoincrementable(1,2,3,etc) nombre, y estado(determina si es activo/inactivo).

Ahora debemos ingresar los datos hacia esta tabla:

```
INSERT INTO tipoOperacion
(nombre, estado)
VALUES
('Aparatos Electrodomesticos',1),
('ArtIculos de Merceria',1),
('ArtIculos de Papeleria',1);
```

con esto ingresaras un par de registros(3) si deseas puedes agregar mas, nota que el ID no se coloca dado que es autoincrementable y la BD ya me lo genera, el "1" representa el estado 1=**Activo** 0=**Inactivo** , bien ahora nos resta trael los datos con el lenguaje que desees en este caso sera con **PHP**:

```
<select name="tipoOperacion" id="tipoOperacion" required>
<?php 
  $conn = new mysqli('miHost', 'miUsuario', 'miClave','miBase') 
   or die ('Cannot connect to db') 
$result = $conn->query("select * from tipoOperacion");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row['id'] ?>"><?=$row['nombre']?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Con esto basicamente consulto en mi Base y imprimo los option y dentro de c/u ira imprimiendo el id(1,2,3) espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Que tal Diego al momento de querer crear la tabla en la base de datos me dice La columna clave 'task_id' no existe en la tabla

Comment: revisala @IsaiasAlejandroSanchez ya lo edite

Comment: Pasando al PHP, el select que me muestras la conexion ya la tengo, solo pondria desde el <option> o como?

Comment: si ya posees la conexion solo deberias realizar desde "$result = $conn->query("select * from tipoOperacion");" hacia abajo @IsaiasAlejandroSanchez

Comment: Quitando el $conn-> ya que veo que esa variable la usas para la conexion es correcto? Algo asi quedaria $result = query("select * from tipoOperacion");??

Comment: recuerda que debes de pasarle la conexion a tu query para que se ejecute y traiga resultados..por ello en mi  respuesta esta "$conn->query(.."

Comment: en tu caso si ya tienes una conexion usa esa o vincula a la variable "$conn = MiClaseConexion();"

Comment: Me mostro el siguiente error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result'

Comment: deberias agregar tu codigo para ver como esta tu conexion y el codigo [edit] para poder darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: Ya me modifique el codigo amigo, ya me salen los que tengo agregados en la base de datos, solo que me lo guarda con el id y pues me muestra solo el id y quiero que me muestre el nombre

Comment: fijate que en tu tabla cobertura que es de la consulta debes tener dicho campo "nombre" para que lo pueda mostrar

Comment: Si lo tengo asi como tu me dijiste pero solo cambie el nombre por cobertura, a lo poco que entiendo creo que en la consulta me falta agregar la tabla coberturas en el FROM y relacionarla o me equivoco?

Comment: al hacer "SELECT * FROM coberturas" estas cogiendo todos los campos de tu tabla, el "*" significa todos los campos y luego de la palabra FROM viene la tabla deseada ahora dentro de "coberturas" debes estar seguro que exista ese campo que deseas mostrar en esta caso "nombre"

Comment: para relacionar una tabla con otra(s) usa : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Modifique el select mas creo que esta mal por que me sigue saliendo el id de la cobertura y no el nombre ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?